# OpenGL: set glPrint() location relative to screen

Tags: c++, opengl, text

I am trying to print some debugging info (FPS, camera location and rotation, etc) in the lower left of the screen. I have set it up so that it works fine using `glTranslate()` and `glRasterPos2f()`, but if I try and resize the window, the text is no longer resting perfectly in the corner, and depending on how much I stretch out the window, it may appear in the middle of the screen, or it may start getting cut off. Is there any way to use `glPrint()` to print text that will be say, 10px from the left, and 10px to the right?

Here is the code I am using:

```
GLvoid glPrint(const char *fmt, ...){                   // Custom GL "Print" Routine
    char        text[256];                              // Holds Our String
    va_list     ap;                                     // Pointer To List Of Arguments
    va_start(ap, fmt);                                  // Parses The String For Variables
        vsprintf(text, fmt, ap);                        // And Converts Symbols To Actual Numbers
    va_end(ap);                                         // Results Are Stored In Text

    glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT);                          // Pushes The Display List Bits
    glListBase(base - 32);                              // Sets The Base Character to 32
    glCallLists(strlen(text), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, text);  // Draws The Display List Text
    glPopAttrib();                                      // Pops The Display List Bits
}

void GLOUT(float xLocation, float yLocation, float colorRed, float colorGreen, float colorBlue){
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0,0,-.002);
    glColor3f(colorRed,colorGreen,colorBlue);
    glRasterPos2f(xLocation/10000, yLocation/10000);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick with rendering HUDs or other overlay stuff, is to switch to a more convenient combination of viewport and projection for them.

You're not forced to stick to one particular projection with OpenGL. Let me guess: You setup viewport and projection in the window's resizing handler, right? Suggestion: Move that code to the drawing function, and (hopefully) have an epiphany doing so.